# Android: fragment backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments

In `ExerciceActivity` I show `ExerciceFragment`:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ...

        addFragment(ExerciceFragment.newInstance(exerciceId), ExerciceFragment.TAG);
    }
```

From `ExerciceFragment` I start another fragment by using  EventBus

library. The event is being caught in `ExerciceActivity` :

```
public void onEvent(ShowExercicePhotosGalleryEvent event) {
        addFragment(ExercicePhotosGalleryFragment.newInstance(event), ExercicePhotosGalleryFragment.TAG);
    }
```

To pop up`ExerciceFragment` from `Fragment` backstack I did this:

```
private void exit() {
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            fm.popBackStack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

All is perfect here. In `ShowExercicePhotosGalleryEvent` I modify `toolbarAppearance(alpha=0)`. And when I come back to `ExerciceFragment` I want to restore my initial toolbar. So, which method is called when I come back to `ExerciceFragment` ?

Thank you guys!